# Blender closing/crashing for no apparent reason

Tags: error

I am currently using Blender 2.83 LTS version and it keeps crashing for no apparent reason.

It started 2 weeks ago. I was using Blender 2.81 on Win 8.1 OS at that time and I was getting the 'NVIDIA graphic driver stoped and recovered' error message than. I have checked and updated my NVIDIA grapics drivers and the problem persisted, the only difference being that after the driver update Blender did not show any messages uppon crashing, it just froze for a few seconds and closed mid work (I did not notice any specific circumstances for crashing like for example only while rendering).

I upgraded my OS to Win 10 Pro but Blender still kept on crashing. Ive checked and updated graphics & CPU drivers again and installed Blender 2.83 LTS yesterday to no avail.

I've run Blender in --debug mode from CMD. When it 'crashes' is doesn't print anything so I am left clueless with what is wrong and how to address this problem. I can only work for a few minutes until it crashes.

Can someone please help me troubleshoot this as I am unable to crack the problem with my current google-foo? Thank you !

Edit:
As suggested below I have run blender --debug-all --factory-startup. Just as I started fidling with some material nodes it crashed imediately.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try starting with `--debug-all --factory-startup`

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this? I have the same problem and have no idea how to do this

Comment: Hey, thank you for replying. I've run it as you've suggested. There is a lot of text to sift through here so Iam not sure what to look for. Nothing obvious is standing out so far.

Comment: @GlenP

You can open command prompt on a Windows OS if you type cmd in the run window. You can than navigate to the folder where your Blender app is located and launch it from there if you type in 'blender'. If you want to launch it in the 'debug' mode you add  ' --debug'  after the blender command like so : blender --debug

That will run blender and also check/log for errors while runing it

Comment: Hmmm. That's strange.What kind of card do you have? Are you using CUDA or OptiX?

Comment: I have GeForce GTX 960M and Intel Core i7 - 4720HQ CPU @ 2.60 GHz on my laptop.

Comment: If this started suddenly, there is a chance that the graphics card is at the end of its useable life. Nvidia GTX can overheat and fail, giving all kinds of random errors, or no error at all. I've gone through many of them that died on me. Test the card in a different computer and start saving for a new card.

Comment: Probably so. Blender crashed a few (a lot) more times today and the last time it did I got the BSOD and the stop code VIDEO_TDR_FAILURE  (nvlddmkm.sys). After some googling it looks like there is not much left for me to do. I will try reinstalling NVIDIA drivers from safe mode and if that doesn't solve the problem than it is probably game over for my graphics card. Thaks to everyone for your responses and time.

Answer (score 1):

After disabling my GPU Blender resumed to working normally so the reason for constant crashing is obviously in faulty GPU; no amount or mode of driver re-installment solved the problem.

Thank you all for your help.